# How to load GridView images with AsyncTask?

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I have, below the following fragment that populates a gridview with Bitmaps from URLs. The problem is that I know it's very 'heavy' work and done on the UI Thread so it's slowing the fragment down when loading the grid.

I've read that an AsyncTask is needed to carry out the 'heavy' work in the background but I can't find anything that seems to fit with what I want.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

protected static final String TAG = null;
public HomeFragment(){}
GridView gridView;
private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;
private SQLiteHandler db;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

GPSTracker gps;
String uid;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());
    gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());


    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);

    uid="1";
    String email = db.getFromTable(getActivity(), "email", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_LOGIN, "WHERE _id="+uid);
    String from_age = db.getFromTable(getActivity(), "from_age", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "WHERE uid="+uid);
    String to_age = db.getFromTable(getActivity(), "to_age", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "WHERE uid="+uid);
    String distance = db.getFromTable(getActivity(), "distance", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "WHERE uid="+uid);
    String unit = db.getFromTable(getActivity(), "unit", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "WHERE uid="+uid);
    String men = db.getFromTable(getActivity(), "men", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "WHERE uid="+uid);
    String women = db.getFromTable(getActivity(), "women", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_SETTINGS, "WHERE uid="+uid);

    fetchUsers(email, from_age, to_age, distance, unit,  men, women);

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    //getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.home);

    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);


    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            //Create intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
            int[] screenLocation = new int[2];
            imageView.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation);
            intent.putExtra("left", screenLocation[0]).
            putExtra("top", screenLocation[1]).
            putExtra("width", imageView.getWidth()).
            putExtra("height", imageView.getHeight()).
            putExtra("uid", item.getUid());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            //my update process
            Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("0");
            FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment); 
            fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment); 
            fragTransaction.commit(); 
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

 // Prepare some dummy data for gridview
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.getAllRows("*", SQLiteHandler.TABLE_USERS, "");
    //Query local DB to initialize settings screen

    for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
        String uid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_UID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_NAME));
        String dob = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_DOB));
        //String gender = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_GENDER));
        String photourl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_PHOTOURL));
        //String distance = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_DISTANCE));

        String[] birthdayArr = dob.split("-");

        int age = getAge(Integer.parseInt(birthdayArr[0]), Integer.parseInt(birthdayArr[1]), Integer.parseInt(birthdayArr[2]));

        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(photourl);

        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, name+" - " + age, uid));
    }
    return imageItems;
}


public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    try { 
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception 
        return null; 
    } 
} 

public int getAge(int year, int month, int day) {
    //int nowMonth = now.getMonth()+1;
    int nowMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //int nowYear = now.getYear()+1900;
    int nowYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int result = nowYear - year;

    if (month > nowMonth) {
        result--;
    }
    else if (month == nowMonth) {
        int nowDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);

        if (day > nowDay) {
            result--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    Log.i("hideDialog",  "called");
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}

public void fetchUsers(final String email, final String agefrom, final String ageto, final String distance, final String distanceUnit, final String interested_men, final String interested_wmen){
    // Tag used to cancel the request

    gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";
    pDialog.setMessage("Finding users ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fetch Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        int success = jObj.getInt("success");
                        JSONArray users = jObj.getJSONArray("users");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (success == 1) {

                            //Log.i("success", users+"");

                            if (users.length() == 0) {
                               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No users found! \nPlease try again soon.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                               db.emptyTable(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_USERS);
                            }else{
                                db.emptyTable(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_USERS);
                                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String uid = user.getString("uid");
                                    String name = user.getString("name");
                                    String dob = user.getString("dob");
                                    String gender = user.getString("gender");
                                    String photourl = user.getString("photoUrl");
                                    String distance = user.getString("distance");

                                    String[][] userValues = {   
                                            { SQLiteHandler.KEY_UID, uid},
                                            { SQLiteHandler.KEY_NAME, name},
                                            { SQLiteHandler.KEY_DOB, dob},
                                            { SQLiteHandler.KEY_GENDER, gender},
                                            { SQLiteHandler.KEY_PHOTOURL, photourl},
                                            { SQLiteHandler.KEY_DISTANCE, distance}
                                    };
                                    db.insert(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_USERS, userValues);
                                } 
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Error in login. Get the error message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            //$lat, $lng, $email, $agefrom, $ageto, $distance, $distanceUnit, $interested_men, $interested_wmen
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "login");
            params.put("lat", gps.getLatitude()+"");
            params.put("lng", gps.getLongitude()+"");
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("agefrom", agefrom);
            params.put("ageto", ageto);
            params.put("distance", distance);
            params.put("distanceUnit", distanceUnit);
            params.put("interested_men", interested_men+"");
            params.put("interested_wmen", interested_wmen+"");
            params.put("fetch", "y");
            Log.i(TAG, params+"");
            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}
}
```

Comment: If you have the luxury of using a 3rd party library, Picasso will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Unless you're doing an exercise to learn about the very very complicated issues and threading and memory management the general advice is: just use a library, nothing good will come out of trying to re-invent the wheel. Search for Picasso or Glide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [fractalwrench](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5144991/fractalwrench) and [Budius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906362/budius), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) was a very good and VERY easy solution to this. All I had to do was to pass the photo url instead of the entire BitMap through to my GridView adapter and use `Picasso.with(context).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.image);` to create the BitMap for the image view. This was so easy to implement and gives me exactly what I need. Thaks

Answer (score 0):

> How to load GridView images with AsyncTask?

Downloading images as Bitmap in `HomeFragment`. Use `NetworkImageView` from [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html) in layout of GridView item for loading images in GridView.

Instead of storing `Bitmap`, store image url in `ImageItem`.

See following tutorial for more help:

[Using NetworkImageView](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/showcase/8/)

Answer (score 0):

AsynTask class

```
public class GridDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<GridDataAsyncTask.GridCallback, Void, GridAdapter> {

public interface GridCallback {
    void onAdapterReady(GridAdapter adapter);
}

private GridCallback mCallBack;

@Override
protected GridAdapter doInBackground(GridCallback... callbacks) {
    mCallBack = callbacks[0];


    // TODO get data and create grid adapter

    return adapter;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(GridAdapter gridAdapter) {
    super.onPostExecute(gridAdapter);
    mCallBack.onAdapterReady(gridAdapter);
}
}
```

Activity

```
public class GridActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GridDataAsyncTask.GridCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new GridDataAsyncTask().execute(this);
}

@Override
public void onAdapterReady(GridAdapter adapter) {
    // TODO set adapte to GridView
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html and make a lru cache and place the images in lru cache.
Example is given in android tutorials
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html